# Adding More Tick Labels To ZedGraph Axis?

Tags: zedgraph

I have tick labels on about every 4 ticks.  This is great, but I want labels on every single tick, and I want to say that each tick should be an hour apart.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit properties of the `Scale` of your `XAxis`:

- to change the gap between ticks edit the `MinorStep` and `MajorStep` properties. For both, use the value that corresponds to your one-hour-gap.
- to display labels at every tick, AFAIR you should set `IsPreventLabelOverlap` to false.
- try also editing `MajorTic` and `MinorTic` of your `XAxis`

Remember to call `AxisChange()` method and `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` in order to refresh your graph with new scale settings.

If you have long labels, it is also useful to set the `Angle` property of `FontSpec` to 90 to draw long labels vertically, instead of horizontally (it saves a lot of space).

More info:
http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_Scale.htm